# Linked List - data in previous nodes is being overwritten

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have a program that puts the directories in a linked list and prints it. The linked list is getting messed up with all nodes having the same data. For example, I have a folder "Test' which has 3 subfolders "Good One", "Jump", "Sunday". The output is -> Sunday Sunday Sunday.

On debug, first iteration of insert function, the variable data in the 1st node is set to "Good One". The address of the root node pointer is passed back to the main.
Initially, startptr->data = "Good One". After readdir is executed, dir->d_name is "Jump".But startptr->data is getting changed to "Jump". same happens for the 3rd "Sunday" and all the nodes in the list have data = "Sunday".

Not sure why this is happening. Appreciate any help on this.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

/* self-referential structure */
struct listNode {
    char *data; /* each listNode contains a character */
    struct listNode *nextPtr; /* pointer to next node */
}; /* end structure listNode */

typedef struct listNode ListNode; /* synonym for struct listNode */
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr; /* synonym for ListNode* */

/* prototypes */
void insert( ListNodePtr *sPtr, char *value );
void printList( ListNodePtr currentPtr );

int main( void )
{
    ListNodePtr startPtr = NULL; /* initially there are no nodes */

    DIR *d = NULL;
    struct dirent *dir = NULL;

    d = opendir ("/Users/Satish/Documents/Test");
    if (d != NULL)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir (d)) != NULL)
        {
            /*printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);*/
            if ( (strcmp(dir->d_name, ".")  == 0) || (strcmp(dir->d_name, "..")  == 0) ) 
            {
            }
            else
                insert( &startPtr, dir->d_name ); /* insert item in list */
        }
        closedir (d);
    }
    else
        printf("%s/n", "Couldn't open the directory");

    printList( startPtr );
    printf( "End of run.\n" );
    return 0; /* indicates successful termination */
} /* end main */

/* Insert a new value into the list in sorted order */
void insert( ListNodePtr *sPtr, char *value )
{
    ListNodePtr newPtr = NULL; /* pointer to new node */
    ListNodePtr previousPtr = NULL; /*pointer to previous node in list */
    ListNodePtr currentPtr = NULL; /* pointer to current node in list */

    printf("%s\n", value);
    newPtr = malloc( sizeof( ListNode ) ); /* create node */

    if ( newPtr != NULL )  /* is space available */
    {
        newPtr->data = value; /* place value in node */
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL; /* node does not link to another node */

        previousPtr = NULL;
        currentPtr = *sPtr;

        if (currentPtr == NULL)
            *sPtr = newPtr;
        else
        {
            while ( currentPtr != NULL ) 
            {
                previousPtr = currentPtr;
                currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
            }
            previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
            newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        printf( "%c not inserted. No memory available.\n", value );
    } /* end else */

} /* end function insert */


/* Print the list */
void printList( ListNodePtr currentPtr )
{
    /* if list is empty */
    if ( currentPtr == NULL ) {
        printf( "List is empty.\n\n" );
    } /* end if */
    else {
        printf( "The list is:\n" );

        /* while not the end of the list */
        while ( currentPtr != NULL ) {
            printf( "%s\n", currentPtr->data );
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        } /* end while */

        printf( "NULL\n\n" );
    } /* end else */
} /* end function printList */
```

**Output is:**

**The list is:**
Sunday
Sunday
Sunday

Comment: Your list elements store a reference to the char buffer in `dir`, which will be overwritten by subsequent calls to `readdir`. You must store a copy of the string in your list. (That means that you have to allocate memory, too. The non-standard function `strdup` might be useful.)

Comment: Thanks for the response.....I am not exactly sure how to do this.....would appreciate if u can provide more details.

Comment: I've made that an answer with example code.

Answer (score 4):

In the `insert` function you are pointing to the same address for all the elements you have to allocate memory to store the name. see line 57 of your code and add this:

```
    newPtr = malloc( sizeof( ListNode ) ); /* create node */
   if ( newPtr != NULL )  /* is space available */
   {
    char *val=malloc((strlen(value)+1)*1);
    strcpy(val,value);
    newPtr->data = val; /* place value in node */
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: The answer is good in principle, but `strlen(value + 1)` will determine the length of the string after the first char, so it wil be the length minus 1. You probably mean `strlen(value) + 1`, which properly allocates enough space for the string and the null terminator.

Comment: Thanks a lot....it works. Now trying to figure out the free function call

Answer (score 1):

In `insert`, you assign the string like this:

```
newPtr->data = value;
```

This stores a reference to the string in the `dirent` struct. This will always be a pointer to the same buffer, but the buffer will have different contents each time you create a link. When you print it, that buffer will of course have the contents of the last entry. (And when the `dirent` struct goes out of scope the pointer goes stale: It will point to invalid data. That's not the case in your code, though.)

To store the actual value, you must create a copy. Thzat copy need storage, which you must allocate:

```
newPtr->data = malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
strcpy(newPtr->data, value);
```

Every `malloc` needs a corresponding `free`, so don't forget to free the memory for the string when you destroy your list.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate a lot for the info.....Is the free(newPtr) and free(value) made at the end of the insert function?

Comment: No. It is made when you no longer need your linked list. Once you have called `free` on a pointer that you have allocated memory to, that pointer will no longer point to valid data. So in your case, the `free` wil probably happen at the end of your program. I recommend to write a function that "destroys" your list: It should free the memory allocated to the strings and the memory allocated to the link nodes. The rule ist simple: Each successful `malloc` must have its corresponding ´free` and the "lifetime"  of the memory lies between these two calls.

Comment: Thank you.......So at the end of the program after printlist in main - I read the list again, delete the nodes and do a free?

Comment: Yes, walk the list, free the string, save the `nextPtr`, free the node itself, and then processthe next item. (You must save the `nextPtr`, because after freeing the node, its data won't be legally accessible any longer.) It's good to make a habit of freeing your data after use.